# Exclude specific paths during triggering TFS team build

Tags: tfs, build, continuous-integration

I'm configuring continuous integration with TFS 2012. I have one problem need solve.
I need to exclude some paths from triggering builds.

For e.g. I have:

1. $/Project1
2. $/Project2

And I want that after each check-in of $/Project1 - build has been triggered. And it must build both $/Project1 and $/Project2.
But after checking in $/Project2 I don't want to trigger a build for that Build Definition.

In Source Settings of Build Definition are only functions "Active" and "Cloaked", but it isn't what I need.

Thanks a lot in advance.

P.S. The worth solution is to add the comment `***NO_CI***` on check-in. It will be great if there is some other way.

Comment: Why do you have two dependant project folders? Should they not be part of the same solution?

Comment: create 2 builds, build 1 for project 1 which then triggers build 2 for project 2 when it completes?

Comment: @MrHinsh, What would be changed if theses projects are under the same team project or the same solution? The problem remains. I need TFS to ignore check-ins from certain path/project and not trigger a build. But not cloaked. I need it to be built with the other projects, when they(other project) are checked-in.

Comment: @JustTFS , is it possible in TFS native continuous integration tool? As far as I know there's no any dependency between TFS build definitions. Each build definition is independent item, which has it's own workflow.
I know how to do it e.g. in Jenkins or Team City, but not in TFS.
But if you know such a method, I'd like you share it with me. I would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If in the same solution then they will both be built if needed on demand in the correct order. Then you need not care about the issue.

Comment: Maybe if you explain why you need to care about this type of orchastration.

Comment: @MrHinsh , The order of the build isn't the point. I can manage the projects build order.

First project is main project. Second project is UI tests project. And I want to not trigger a build, deployment, and test after checking in UI test project.
Because there may be implemented some tests, which functionality haven't been checked in yet in main project. And tests will fail. I want that the build has been triggered only after main project has been checked in.

Comment: Dude, why are you checking in when you have tests that test functionality that does not yet exist? You should only ever check in working code. Making the project optional is nefarious to that purpose.

Comment: Cant you just comment out the tests that are not ready yet?

Comment: @MrHinsh , We get task - e.g. "add this input field, with this functionality".
And subtasks - "make DB development", "make application development", "make UI tests development" for that task.
I already know where must be added that input field, and how I must work with it. So I write the test case for it and check-in. But I don't want to trigger the CI process untill the implementation of that field is not checked in.

Comment: I already have some workaround, that I have described in main post - I can just write in check-in comment `***NO_CI***`, and the build won't be triggered. But I want to find better solution to not trigger a build.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, this boils down to an X-Y problem. You can't do what you want to do, but the reason you want to do it is because you're trying to solve the wrong problem.

You're running the UI tests at the wrong point in your dev-test cycle. UI tests should not run during a build, they should run after a release. A change to your test project should absolutely result in a build.

Someone is developing UI tests against code that's not yet in source control, which makes no sense. If someone is writing tests against code, the code should be source controlled.

I'm guessing that someone is manually pushing uncommitted code out to a dev server, which is being used by someone else to write tests. Don't do this. Use a real release management solution so that as developers write code, each check-in is automatically deployed to a dev/QA environment. Then the folks writing the UI tests will have something to test against. What's the point in writing tests against code that's in such a state of flux that the developer responsible for it isn't even sure it's worth being source controlled? That just results in spending a lot of time rewriting tests as the code evolves.

Assuming you set everything up properly, every commit of the application code will result in the current set of tests being run against the latest commit. Every commit of the test code will result in the new set of tests being run against the existing application code. The two things (application code and test code) **should** be coupled, and **should** always build together.

And one last thing, mostly opinion: UI tests are awful and serve very little utility. They are brittle, slow, and hard to maintain. I have never seen a comprehensive UI test suite actually provide value. UI tests are best served as a small set of post-release smoke tests. Business logic should be primarily unit tested, with a smaller suite of integration tests to back it up.

Comment: Out sounds worse to me @Daniel; it sounds like they are trying to work around checking in working code. Being a sea lawyer does not increase the quality...

Comment: @Daniel, I run tests at right point. I've developed not only continuous integration, and also continuous deployment and continuous delivery. When I check-in the changes - in short the following process start: 
perform static code review->change version->compile->run unit tests->deploy/install(App, DB etc.)->run UI tests on new deployed app etc.
And all that processes are in 1 build definition.

Comment: We get task - e.g. "add this input field, with this functionality". And subtasks - "make DB development", "make application development", "make UI tests development" for that task. I already know where must be added that input field, and how I must work with it. So I write the test case for it and check-in. But I don't want to trigger the CI process until the implementation of that field is not checked in.

Comment: And about the comparison of unit and UI tests, and also about your opinion.
Classic Unit tests never can be used as substitute of UI tests, and neither vice versa, because they have different purposes.
Unit tests can be used just to test the program in code level - functional acceptance/integration tests - the function work as expected - it get expected/unexpected count of arguments of particular type, and return expected result. And functions in program interact with each other also as expected, etc.

Comment: But with unit tests you can not test the client side/front-end. You can not be sure that UI elements are clearly integrated with back-end and perform the correct functions and do what it need to do, especially considering browser specific features/issues etc.

P.S. And about maintainability. You just haven't seen my created UI test project, and probably because of it you think that UI tests are awful and hard to maintain ;)))
Whatever - the importance of automated UI testing is not a subject of discussion for me, as I see advantages of it clearly.